# tkinter not getting installed | dont have sudo access

Tags: python, tkinter, pip, centos, yum

I have tried Pip3 install tkinter, pip3 install tk-devel, python -m pip install tkinter
,python -m pip install tk-tools but nothing seems to be working. I dont have sudo so I can't use yum.

I read it comes installed with python 3.7, so I installed 3.7 and created a virtual env for 3.7. But no luck.

Can anyone please help me here.

Note : My distribution is Centos.

Comment: pip3 install tk or pip install tk. Another thing is python comes with tkinter.

Comment: tkinter cannot be installed via pip.

Comment: You can try downloading the tkinter package from CentOS repository, unzip it to a directory and then set the env variable PYTHONPATH to include the directory.

Comment: @toyotaSupra It does install. says Successfully installed tk-0.1.0. 
but I still get "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'".

I am building a package using python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel --user.

Can you please suggest why I still getting Modulenotfound error

Comment: @acw1668 let me try downloading from centos repo.

Comment: @acw1668 I can find the .rpm package only, it would require sudo yum installation, can you share tkinter zip link please

Comment: @toyotaSupra by re-install you are referring to which command?

Comment: Try this sudo yum install python3-tkinter. Or sudo yum install python37u-tkinter Or yum install python37-tkinter

Comment: @toyotaSupra I dont have sudo access, that's the problem, I need an alternative.

Comment: A RPM file is some kind of archive file that you can open with 7-zip.  I use `mc` (midnight-commander) to open it and copy the files inside it to other directory.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Yeah had tried, it says 

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, ovl
ovl: Error while doing RPMdb copy-up:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/rpm/Name'
You need to be root to perform this command